# Downloading zip file using Python give HTTP 403

Tags: python, zip

I am using request module in Python to download a zip file from internet.
I am getting 403 error while trying so.

The file is following a pattern in the server so i am able to generate url dynamically. It is working till the date 31-Dec-2020. But not after this.

Workable URL: https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2020/DEC/cm31DEC2020bhav.csv.zip
Non workable URL: https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2021/JAN/cm01JAN2021bhav.csv.zip

Python Code:

```
formattedUrl='https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2021/JAN/cm01JAN2021bhav.csv.zip'
requestedFile = requests.get(formattedUrl)
requestedFile.status_code
```

Also tried this:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests

ua_str = UserAgent().chrome
formattedUrl='https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2021/JAN/cm01JAN2021bhav.csv.zip'
requestedFile = requests.get(formattedUrl,headers={"User-Agent": ua_str})
requestedFile.status_code
```

Also tried this:

```
import zipfile, urllib.request, shutil

url = formattedUrl
file_name = 'cm01JAN2021bhav.csv.zip'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        zf.extractall()
```

None of them are working.
Any suggestion.

Regards.

EDIT: Adding more details as some comments says it is not allowed to download the file or need some kind of authentication.
I am able to download it via there page. There is no authentication required.
Visit: https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm
Select Report: Bhavcopy
Date: 01-01-2021
Hit Get Data
You will get the file link clicking on which will download the file.
Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Python. The server is simply unwilling to provide that file: either it doesn't actually exist, or it requires some form of authentication to access it. Try to access the URL in your browser and you'll get the same error.

Comment: Error 403 means you don't have permission to access that file

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check. Basically you can download without any authentication. You can just follow the steps i have mention,

Comment: It's 3 now.  Clicking on the two URLs you provide above reproduces the problem in a browser.  The first link works.  The second one does not.  So this is an issue with the web site in question and has nothing to do with programming an HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issue the below code resolves my problem, guess u need to hit 2 extra URL's and use the cookies it returns

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.63',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Host': 'www1.nseindia.com',
            'Referer':'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin'}
resp1 = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm',headers=headers)
print(resp1)
resp2 = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=eqbhav&date=05-01-2021&section=EQ',headers=headers,cookies=resp1.cookies)
print(resp2)
resp3 = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2021/JAN/cm05JAN2021bhav.csv.zip',headers=headers)
print(resp3.content)
with open('c:/temp/test.zip', 'wb') as handle:
    for block in resp3.iter_content(1024):
        if not block:
            break
        handle.write(block)
```